# Want to increase the # of slides in FlexSlider in WooThemes Scrollider

Tags: slideshow

I am using WooThemes Scrollider for a full screen homepage slide show.  The client has chosen 14 slides to include, but the slider only lets me set 10.  Is there a way to change the maximum # of slides allowed in FlexSlider?

Thanks so much!

Comment: have you tried woothemes support? being that it is a premium theme, we don't have access to the code. the flexslider script on its own places no limit on the number of slides, so it's an issue with the specific implementation within that particular theme.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  That is helpful unto itself.  I tried changing the flexslider js to no avail.